# Turn off grammar correction in a contenteditable div in FireFox

Tags: javascript, html, firefox, text, contenteditable

I have contenteditable div with text on it. In firefox, there is some kind of grammar correction which underlines the text with red marking. How can I turn it off?
[image: Why-do.you-underline-me-image]

How do I turn off the red markings in FireFox?

```
<div contenteditable ='true'>Why do you underline me?</div>
```

JSFiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/26JkW/

Comment: @Woho87: By spelling your words correctly? ;-D

Comment: It is actually not a grammar correction. It is something different. Don't know yet what it is

Comment: @Woho87: See -- http://jsfiddle.net/26JkW/3/

Comment: @stealthyninja - all misspelled words are underlined in your example.  I suspect this might be caused by the parent container from JSFiddle itself.

Comment: @Chris: Which version of Firefox are you using? Try -- http://jsfiddle.net/26JkW/5/

Comment: That one did it for me in terms of stopping spell checks (v4.0 + Firebug).  I don't, however, think it will help in WoHo87's case - I am convinced he has a larger issue going on.  Good tip though, haven't heard of this property, so thanks for that!

Comment: +1 for Stealthninja solution to remove all spelling-check from Firefox.

Comment: Strange nested element behaviour: http://jsfiddle.net/qxqpcszj/1/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no grammar-checking native to Firefox.  Given that every word is being marked as incorrect, it is possible that you have the wrong language selected.

To verify that you have the correct language selected for Firefox's dictionary:  When typing in an editable field, right-click the input area.  From the context menu, there is an option Languages.  Ensure the expected language is selected.

---

**EDIT** [stealthyninja's answer below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5782890/610573) contains the method for disabling spell checking as the OP requested. This answer should not be taken as the solution.

Comment: Look at JsFiddle first. If there is red markings then it is not a language problem

Comment: It is not underlined for me at all.  This reinforces my assertion that there is an issue with your dictionary.  If you have verified that you have the correct language selected, then the next step would be to diagnose your dictionary file.

Comment: Check under Tools->Options, flip to the content tab.  There, you can change the language setting for your browser.  Open that dialog (click the "choose" button) and ensure English is selected there.

Comment: I use the swedish firefox, that's why it marks it red. But can I turn it off somehow using javascript?

Comment: You can't turn off or change the dictionary from JS, nor would that be a good idea.  You can, using the method stealthyninja provided, turn off spell checking on a container.  This one worked for me: http://jsfiddle.net/26JkW/5/

Comment: If you look at his **second** example, he ended up having to apply the `spellcheck` property to the body rather than the element.  I am not certain if this is fully required or what, but I can tell you that it appears to work when you do it that way.

Comment: @Woho87: Eh...if my example worked shouldn't my answer be credited as the answer? ;-P

Answer (score 21):

Try --

```
<textarea spellcheck="false"></textarea>
```

Since the above is a Firefox-only attribute, if you're concerned about validation, you can also use jQuery to set the attribute, e.g.

```
$('.textarea_you_want_to_target').attr('spellcheck', false);
```

**Update**

It seems in Firefox you have to set `spellcheck="false"` on `<body>`. See http://jsfiddle.net/26JkW/5/

Comment: This solution doesn't work. First of all it is a `div-element`

Comment: @Woho87: Just add `spellcheck="false"` to the `div`, e.g. `<div contenteditable spellcheck="false">`. It works for me.

Comment: As I mentioned above, the example is underlining words as it would normally.  I am not experiencing the issue the OP mentions, but the code also does not accomplish the desired results (using latest Firefox +Firebug)

Comment: @Chris: If it's also doing it in http://jsfiddle.net/26JkW/5/ for you, then I'm all out of ideas.

Comment: Heh, no, we're splitting up our conversation :P  Your second iteration worked for me, +1.  I think the issue at play here is a combination of our suggestions - he is using Swedish Firefox, so it is hiliting all English as misspelled.

Comment: yep.I had to add spellcheck="false" on <body> to disable spellcheck. Simly adding to div element didn't work for me. thanks for the tip.

Comment: On FF 57 (much later), setting this attribute on a particular element worked for me.

Answer (score 4):

According to [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTML/Controlling_spell_checking_in_HTML_forms):

> Starting in Gecko 9.0 (Firefox 9.0 / Thunderbird 9.0 / SeaMonkey 2.6),
>   the spell checker uses the `<input>` element's lang attribute to
>   determine the default spell checker language. If `<input>` doesn't
>   have a lang attribute, that attribute is searched each successive
>   parent element and upward toward the root node until one is found.

So to disable spellcheck, not only do I add `spellcheck="false"`, but I also add a `lang` tag with a dictionary not found on the users computer.

```
<div contentEditable="true" lang="klingon" spellcheck="false"></div>
```

This should work on most systems outside of Kronos.

Comment: You should use [`lang="zxx"` for all "No linguistic content"](http://www.iana.org/assignments/language-subtag-registry/language-subtag-registry)

Comment: Are you saying that the Firefox process first searches for `lang="ABC"` and then the `spellcheck="false"` must be in that exact same tag otherwise it gets ignored?